# Vimperator is not compatible with Firefox 18.0

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Today I find that Vimperator (3.8) is not compatible with Firefox 18.0. 
This makes me really upset. I've tried other add-ons like VimFx but I think Vimperator is the best.

Do you have any solutions other than changing the Firefox 18 back to Firefox 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum compatible Firefox version to work with Vimperator 3.8 is Firefox v20, as you can see from its own [install.rdf manifest](https://addons.mozilla.org/el/firefox/files/browse/230597/). So you will have to either update Firefox or if this isn't possible for some reason, find an older version of Vimperator.